# Storing POST data in SESSION

Tags: php, session, forms, post

I'm creating a multi-step survey and want to store the data in `$_SESSION` before writing everything to a database. Is there anything I should be doing to the data before storing it there from a security perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're on the regular file-based sessions, then you don't have much to worry about from an injection vulnerability view. PHP will take care of the mechanics of read/writing the session file, using `serialize()` and the like. Stuff whatever you want into $_SESSION and it'll magically be there on the next page invocation.

However, from the broader security perspective, anything that goes into the session file IS readable by anything else running under the same web server instance (e.g. the apache user ID). So it's not somewhere you could store sensitive data, let along things like credit cart/cvv numbers.

Answer (score 3):

well, to avoid problems recovering the data, i suggest you to use a name for the session and use an array exclusively for the post data, kinda:

> $_SESSION['postData'] = $_POST;

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly safe to throw whatever you want in the session without sanitizing it.  You could though, since you're going to anyways, sanitize it before putting it in the session so its ready to go into the database, then you can sleep more soundly.

Comment: as long as the variables are not passed my reference and there's caution used with objects

Comment: that's wrong approach. the data may go everywhere - email, back into form on some errors, etc. And, to let you know - session handler IS NOT the friggin place to do anything related to database. It should be database handler where data being properly prepared.

Comment: That doesn't mean my answer deserves a down vote. Im not arguing how he does it, I just answered his question.  It is not necessary to sanitize data before putting it in the session.  If he's planning on re-displaying it, or emailing it, that's his issue to worry about.  He mentioned nothing of the sort.  Just storing it while they go on to the next steps. Colonel troll strikes again.

Comment: uh oh, a downvote. Just whine long enough and good guys will upvote you back, just for charity

Comment: I'm not concerned about my rep. Its a decent answer, which will hopefully give the guy some direction, as opposed to the counter productive garbage you always post.